# modern analysis: limits, integrals, uniform

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\{f_n\} \to f$ uniformly on $[a, b]$ and both $f$ and the $f_n$ are integrable. Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^bf_n(x)dx = \int_{a}^bf(x)dx$

Comment: i meant to put equal. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use the uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ to $f$ and the inequality
$$\left|\int_a^b f_n(x)dx-\int_a^b f(x)dx\right|\le\int_a^b||f_n-f||_\infty dx=(b-a)||f_n-f||_\infty$$

Comment: I think there must be a modulus inside the integral on RHS of  inequality

Comment: I don't know why this answer have 2 votes down!!! The idea is fine just change the norm (by the euclidean) and is OK. +1

Comment: @happymath Do you know the uniform convergence norm?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane sorry my mistake

Comment: No problem and you're welcome @happymath

Answer (score 1):

In all these limit integral interchanging the main idea of the proof goes into proving that it is integrable. For example once the function f to which series converges is riemann integrable then we can easily prove that the integral is limit of integral.

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~m43s12/notes/class8.pdf is one proof of the result.

Comment: The paper is fine and contains the proof. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Let epsilon e > 0 be given, choose N such that: / f(n)(x) - f(x) / < e/(b - a)  for n > N and all x in [a, b]. Then:

/ Int(a to b)f(n)(x)dx - Int(a to b)f(x)dx / = / Int(a to b)( f(n)(x) - f(x))dx/ < (b - a)*e/(b - a) = e, and the result follows.